# FreeRadius Accounting Run Script

Tags: freeradius

I am trying to run a script on FreeRadius on accounting when if condition is fulfilled,

```
accounting {
    update control { 
        ...omitted...
        update request {
        Tmp-String-5 := `/path/to/script/script.sh "%{Acct-Session-Id}"`
        }
```

It works, but I got this error when running the script

```
(13)       update request {
(13)         Executing: `/path/to/script/script.sh "%{Acct-Session-Id}":
(13)         EXPAND %{Acct-Session-Id}
(13)            --> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
(13)         ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "`/path/to/script/script.sh": Permission denied'
```

The script itself will do SSH to another server and run a command with acct-session-id as argument.

freeradius is running under freerad (system user), I also tried to configured public key for freerad user to SSH into the other server (key is generated into /etc/freerad/.ssh folder)

If I replace the script with SSH, I will get below

```
ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "ssh": Permission denied'
```

Anyone knows what this permission denied means? does the freerad user cannot execute ssh? and how to allow it?

Thanks!

EDIT

I also test

```
update request {
        Tmp-String-5 := `su otheruser /path/to/script.sh "%{Acct-Session-Id}"`
        }
```

But again still getting this error

```
(12)         ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "su": Permission denied'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working,
instead of only 'ssh', I specify the full path '/usr/bin/ssh' and I don't get the permission error anymore.